# Expand Container without expanding the parent/whole row

Tags: html, css

I want to create a mouseover effect, where more informations are revealed when you hover a parent element.
I came so far:

```css
ul{
  grid-column-gap: 21px;
    grid-row-gap: 40px;
    display: grid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none outside;
    clear: both;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

ul li{
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #EAEAE3;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
}

.additional{
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: height 0.25s ease-out;
}

ul li:hover .additional{
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: height 0.25s ease-in,opacity 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul>
<li>
  Title<br />
  Image<br />
  <div class="additional">
    Line 1<br />
    Line 2<br />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Click here" />
</li>

<li>
  Title<br />
  Image<br />
  <div class="additional">
    Line 1<br />
    Line 2<br />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Click here" />
</li>

<li>
  Title<br />
  Image<br />
  <div class="additional">
    Line 1<br />
    Line 2<br />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Click here" />
</li>

<li>
  Title<br />
  Image<br />
  <div class="additional">
    Line 1<br />
    Line 2<br />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Click here" />
</li>

<li>
  Title<br />
  Image<br />
  <div class="additional">
    Line 1<br />
    Line 2<br />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Click here" />
</li>

<li>
  Title<br />
  Image<br />
  <div class="additional">
    Line 1<br />
    Line 2<br />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Click here" />
</li>



</ul>

</div>
```

How can I achieve that only the hover container expands, but not the rest of the row?
I can/should overlap the 2nd row and overlap their containers.

Comment: For that you will have to involve some absolute positioning, to take the expanding parts out of the normal layout flow.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try setting the container inside a div and setting the parameters in the html file.

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_containers.asp

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of @CBrow was right.
I've created a wrapping `div`, which is absolute positioned insind the relative positioned `li`, which also got a fixed height. For the overlapping I also needed to add a z-index on hover to the "active" element

```css
ul{
    grid-column-gap: 21px;
    grid-row-gap: 40px;
    display: grid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none outside;
    clear: both;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

ul li{
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
    height: 90px;
}

.additional{
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: height 0.25s ease-out;
}

ul li:hover .additional{
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: height 0.25s ease-in,opacity 0.25s ease-in;
}

.container{
    border: 2px solid #EAEAE3;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
  <div classs="container">
    Title<br />
    Image<br />
    <div class="additional">
      Line 1<br />
      Line 2<br />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Click here" />
  </div>
</li>

<li><div classs="container">Title<br />Image<br /><div class="additional">Line 1<br />Line 2<br /></div><input type="submit" value="Click here" /></div></li>

<li><div classs="container">Title<br />Image<br /><div class="additional">Line 1<br />Line 2<br /></div><input type="submit" value="Click here" /></div></li>

<li><div classs="container">Title<br />Image<br /><div class="additional">Line 1<br />Line 2<br /></div><input type="submit" value="Click here" /></div></li>

<li><div classs="container">Title<br />Image<br /><div class="additional">Line 1<br />Line 2<br /></div><input type="submit" value="Click here" /></div></li>

<li><div classs="container">Title<br />Image<br /><div class="additional">Line 1<br />Line 2<br /></div><input type="submit" value="Click here" /></div></li>


</ul>

</div>
```